# Adding buttons dynamically to custom FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have the following **XML** file that is built out of a custom layout that is created via Java code and 3 buttons inside a linear layout below it -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_200"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey_200"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_height="500dp">

        <com.etiennelawlor.tinderstack.ui.TinderStackLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_tinder_stack_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_delete_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:tag="1"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_delete" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_pass_button"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#A9A9A9"
            android:tag="2"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_pass" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_approve_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#98FB98"
            android:tag="3"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_approve" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The issue I am facing looks like this -

[image]

I want the image to be able to move on top of the buttons when touching it, but also of course for the buttons to be touchable and functional.

Here is my TinderStackLayout class -

```
public class TinderStackLayout extends FrameLayout {

  // Constants
  private static final int DURATION = 300;

  // Variable members
  private OnCardSwipedListener onCardSwipedListener;
  private int screenWidth;
  private int yMultiplier;

  //Top card
  private TinderCardView topCardOnStack;

  private Button mDeleteButton, mPassButton, mApproveButton;



  //Constructors
  public TinderStackLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  public TinderStackLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
  }

  public TinderStackLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
  }

  @Override
  public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);
    if (onCardSwipedListener != null)
      onCardSwipedListener.onNext(getChildCount());
  }


  @Override
  public void removeView(View view) {
    super.removeView(view);
    if (onCardSwipedListener != null)
      onCardSwipedListener.onNext(getChildCount());
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
  }

  // Helper Methods
  private void init() {
    setClipChildren(false);

    screenWidth = DisplayUtility.getScreenWidth(getContext());
    yMultiplier = DisplayUtility.dp2px(getContext(), 8);

    mDeleteButton = new Button(getContext());
    mPassButton = new Button(getContext());
    mApproveButton = new Button(getContext());


  }

  public void addCard(TinderCardView tinderCardView) {
    View firstCard = getChildAt(0);

    if (firstCard != null && firstCard.equals(tinderCardView)) {
      return;
    }

    if (onCardSwipedListener == null)
      onCardSwipedListener = tinderCardView.getOnCardSwipedListener();

    topCardOnStack = tinderCardView;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int childCount = getChildCount();
    addView(tinderCardView, 0, layoutParams);

    float scaleValue = 1 - (childCount / 50.0f);

    tinderCardView.animate()
        .x(0)
        .y(childCount * yMultiplier)
        .scaleX(scaleValue)
        .setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator())
        .setDuration(DURATION);
  }

  public TinderCardView getTopCardOnStack() {
    return topCardOnStack;
  }
}
```

Do I need to add them dynamically? or is there a simpler way?
And if I do need to add them dynamically - I would be happy to get a code example of how to do so.

Comment: Check this : https://blog.mindorks.com/android-tinder-swipe-view-example-3eca9b0d4794

Comment: Hi, can you please reference to me the relevant place inside this tutorial to my question? This is a project from scartch which I do not need.

Comment: I think your question is not really clear, it isn't clear what you want to obtain